# Best way to create entity objects from xml using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have following code for creating a list of objects from source `XML`. I can get the requires result in `var query` variable. What is the best way to create a `List<Video>` from this result?

Note: Prefer `Method Chaining` approach if possible.

**CODE**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlStringInput = @"<videoShop>
                                  <video title=""video1"" path=""videos\video1.wma""><Director>Speilberg</Director></video>
                                  <video title=""video2"" path=""videos\video2.wma""/>
                                </videoShop>";

        XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStringInput);


        var videoElements = (from video in myDoc.Descendants("video") select video).ToList();
        foreach (var videoEle in videoElements)
        {
            //System.Xml.XPath namespace for XPathSelectElement
            var directorName = videoEle.XPathSelectElement(@"Director");
        }


        var query = from video in myDoc.Descendants("video")
                    select new
                    {
                        MyTitle = video.Attribute("title").Value,
                        MyPath = video.Attribute("path").Value
                    };

        //IEnumerable<XElement> elements = (IEnumerable<XElement>)query;
        //List<Video> videoLibrary = (List<Video>)query.ToList<Video>();

        Console.WriteLine(query);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

**Entity**

```
 public class Video
 {
     public string MyTitle { get; set; }
     public string MyPath { get; set; }
 }
```

**REFERENCE**:

1. [What's the most efficient way to locate and set element values in an XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299747/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-locate-and-set-element-values-in-an-xdocument)
2. [How do I get a list of child elements from XDocument object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542184/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-child-elements-from-xdocument-object)
3. [Creating objects from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601911/creating-objects-from-xml)
4. [C# LINQ with XML, cannot extract multiple fields with same name into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980263/c-sharp-linq-with-xml-cannot-extract-multiple-fields-with-same-name-into-object?rq=1)
5. [How to get XElement's value and not value of all child-nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251215/how-to-get-xelements-value-and-not-value-of-all-child-nodes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var query = from vin myDoc.Descendants("video")
            select new Video
            {
                MyTitle = (string)v.Attribute("title"),
                MyPath = (string)v.Attribute("path")
            };

// var means List<Video> here
var results = query.ToList();
```

Or without `query` variable:

```
// var means List<Video> here
var results = (from vin myDoc.Descendants("video")
               select new Video
               {
                   MyTitle = (string)v.Attribute("title"),
                   MyPath = (string)v.Attribute("path")
               }).ToList();
```

Method-based query:

```
var results = myDoc.Descendants("video")
                   .Select(v => new Video()
                                {
                                    MyTitle = (string)v.Attribute("title"),
                                    MyPath = (string)v.Attribute("path")
                                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is done by compiler. It detects, that `var results` is actually `List<Video>`